# jquery marquee with previous next buttons?

Tags: jquery, button, marquee

I'm using jQuery marquee and I'm trying to see how to add previous / next buttons, I've tried messing with the function "showNext" but not having any luck. The code I'm using is found here:

http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_jquery_plugin.htm

Example / demo:

http://www.givainc.com/labs/marquee_example.htm

Mention of adding prev/next buttons is here:

http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2009/5/20/Marquee-jQuery-Plugin-Released

But I can't seem to add the buttons and get it working. If someone could help me, that would be fantastic!!

Cheers :)

Comment: In general, users don't like marquee tags, or generally anything that blinks or moves.  They're distracting and annoying.  That said, I understand there are times to use them--but I can't think of any right now.

Comment: Yeh I know, although the client is adamant that they have a news ticker/marquee at the top of the page unfortuantely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this one would suit your needs better. Looks like it already has next and previous built in.

http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/

Comment: But when it comes to long text id do not display.